# How to set scroll in the way that a certain part of the text is visible JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Good Evening, Everybody!
There is an object called TextArea, and I use it to display text,big text of a big  book, making it not Editable. If it's not able to display all the text a the same time, it gains a scroll and displays only a part of itself.

So that's the point, can we set which exactly part of the text, shall be displayed?
Just a kleiner hint, I don't ask more)

P.S. Also, Fisrt, I asked myself a question, what to use to display required text, and didn't find anything better than TextArea, probably, because of a bad seeking. Maybe, someone of you, dear programmers, came across the same problem and found a better solution?

Comment: You do not have to show everything, you can display number of lines(from big string), and by events(like Mouse wheel) push next line of the string to your TextArea,

Comment: And clear the previous, seems like?

Comment: I've given you an example :)

Comment: or see https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to show everything, you can display number of lines(from big string), and by events(like Mouse wheel) push next line of the string to your TextArea

simple Example:

```
public class Controller {
public TextArea text;
int current=0;
int d=1;
int rowSize= 20;
int rowsToSee=10;
String[] strings=null;
@FXML
public void initialize() {
    String string ="";
    for(int i=0;i<3000;i++){
        string=string+" "+i;
        if(i%rowSize==0){
            string=string+"\n";
        }
    }
    strings = string.split("\n");
    final String s=string;

    text.setText(returnLines(current,current+rowsToSee,strings));
    text.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {

            if(event.getDeltaY()<0){
            text.setText(returnLines(current,current+rowsToSee,strings));
                current=current+d;
            }else {
                if(current!=0)
                {   current=current-d;
                    text.setText(returnLines(current,current+rowsToSee,strings));

                }
            }}

    });
}
String returnLines(int from,int to,String[] strArry){
    String s="";
    for(int i=from;i<to;i++){
        if(strArry.length>i){
        s=s+strArry[i]+"\n";
        }
    }
    return s;
}
}
```